# Настройка конфига NGINX для PHP

Tags: php, nginx

Это текущий конфиг

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /Users/*name*/PHPSITE/standard;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /Users/*name*/PHPSITE/standard;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

        include /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index /index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /Users/*name*/PHPSITE/standard$fastcgi_script_name;

     } 

}
```

Но когда запускаю localhost - 403 Forbidden, когда 127.0.0.1:9000 - ничего. Права доступа к папкам выставлено chmod +x. Попытка подключения через телнет к 127.0.0.1:9000 -

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Answer (score 0):

Директива `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000` не означает что NGINX будет слушать на порту 9000.
Она означает что он будет проксировать запросы к FastCGI серверу, слушающему на этом порту.

Соответственно. вы ли либо не сконфигурировали PHP-FPM таким образом, чтобы он слушал на порту 9000, и/или попросту PHP-FPM не запущен.